# SilverStripe 3: How to group a sorted array by grandparent pages

Tags: php, sorting, grouping, silverstripe

I'm trying to loop through all my `ProductPage`s while grouping them by their grandparent's title (as this is the product category). I would also like to sort the product pages under each group by their `ProductReleaseDate` descending. Finally if possible, any that do not have a `ProductReleaseDate` to be listed first before everything.

I have this function in my page controller that grabs all the product pages:

```
function ProductPages() {
    $productPages = ProductPage::get();
    return $productPages ? $productPages : false;
}
```

Then in my template:

```
<% loop $ProductPages.Sort(ProductReleaseDate, DESC) %>
    $Title
<% end_loop %>
```

This displays all my product pages titles in descending order by the ProductReleaseDate they have been given. They now need grouping.

I've been searching hard and can't find the right documentation or examples to get this right. Perhaps I need groupBy? I'm not sure if it needs to be in the controller or the template.

This may help but I need help: http://docs.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/model/how_tos/grouping_dataobject_sets/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SilverStripe 3.1 we can do this with the [`GroupedList`](http://docs.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/model/how_tos/grouping_dataobject_sets/), the one you linked to in your question.

To set it up we first need something to group the items by. Either a variable or a function that returns a value.

In your case we will set up a get function that returns the grand parent title.

**ProductPage.php**

```
class ProductPage extends SiteTree {

    public function getGrandParentTitle() {
        $parent = $this->Parent();
        if ($parent->Exists()) {
            $grandParent = $parent->Parent();
            if ($grandParent->Exists()){
                return $grandParent->Title;
            }
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

Then we need to add a function that will return a `GroupedList`.

**Page.php**

```
class Page extends SiteTree {

    public function getGroupedProducts() {
        return GroupedList::create(ProductPage::get()->sort('ProductReleaseDate', 'DESC'));
    }

}
```

Lastly in our template we called our `GroupedList` function and tell it what to group the items by.

**Your template**

```
<% loop $GroupedProducts.GroupedBy(GrandParentTitle) %>
    <h3>$GrandParentTitle</h3>
    <ul>
        <% loop $Children %>
            <li>$Title</li>
        <% end_loop %>
    </ul>
<% end_loop %>
```

### Group by Parent Title

Or if you want to sort by the parent page title first we will set up a get function that returns the parent title.

**ProductPage.php**

```
class ProductPage extends SiteTree {

    public function getParentTitle() {
        $parent = $this->Parent();
        if ($parent->Exists()) {
            return $parent->Title;
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

Then in our template we called our `GroupedList` function that we created before but this time set `GroupedBy` to `ParentTitle`.

**Your template**

```
<% loop $GroupedProducts.GroupedBy(ParentTitle) %>
    <h3>$ParentTitle</h3>
    <ul>
        <% loop $Children %>
            <li>$Title</li>
        <% end_loop %>
    </ul>
<% end_loop %>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I've just added it and it does what you meant it to do. But I have realised now that they need to be grouped by their Parent not GrandParent. I tried changing the function to this but it's not correct could you suggest the amendment please, many thanks: public function getParentTitle() {
        $parent = $this->Parent();
        if ($parent->Exists()) {
                return $parent->Title;
            }
        }
        return '';
    }

Comment: Happy to help @pinkp . I've added the example code for grouping by Parent Title rather than the Grand Parent. I hope this works for you.

Comment: So great! I had an extra } in mine.. Thanks so much for your time!